# How to set a single field of custom form in django in template

Tags: django

I have a custom Django Form

```
# creating a form
class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):
  
    # create meta class
    class Meta:
        # specify model to be used
        model = Post
  
        # specify fields to be used
        fields = [
            "title",
            "slug",
            "author",
            "content",
            "status",
            "youtubeVideo",
            "category",
            "image",        
        ]
```

I have my view as follows:

```
def create_post(request):
    # dictionary for initial data with 
    # field names as keys
    context ={}
    
    # add the dictionary during initialization
    user = get_user(request)
    form = PostForm(request.POST or None, initial={'author': user})
    if form.is_valid():
        form.fields["author"] = user   
        form.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect("/index")    
    
    context['form']= form
    
    return render(request, "blog/create_post.html", context)
```

How to set the django form template with only my current user?

My django template is as follows:

```
<div class="card-body">
                        {% load crispy_forms_tags %}
                        <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                        
                            <!-- Security token -->
                            {% csrf_token %}
                            <!-- Using the formset -->
                            {{ form | crispy}}


                            <input type="submit" value="Submit">
                        </form>

                    </div>
```

Comment: You want that the posts author should be the current logged in user?

Comment: yes. my dropdown author field shows all my users. I just want the current logged in user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly since the author of the post will be the current user displaying the field itself doesn't make sense so remove that from `fields` in the form class:

```
class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    # create meta class
    class Meta:
        # specify model to be used
        model = Post
        # specify fields to be used
        fields = [
            ...
            "author", # Remove this line
            ...
        ]
```

Next in the view simply alter the instance wrapped by the form before saving it, also no need to use `get_user` as `request.user` already has the user:

```python
def create_post(request):
    # dictionary for initial data with 
    # field names as keys
    context ={}
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = PostForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.instance.author = request.user
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect("/index")
    else:
        form = PostForm()
    context['form']= form    
    return render(request, "blog/create_post.html", context)
```

> **Note**: `SomeForm(request.POST or None)` is an **antipattern** some forms can be valid even **without** any data, in that case your
> implementation would make such forms **invalid** which is why I have
> changed the structure of your view.